# Using flask inside class

Tags: python, flask

I have an application with many threads. One of them is flask, which is used to implement (auxiliary) API. It's used with low load and never exposed to the Internet, so build-in flask web server is perfectly fine.

My current code looks like this:

```
class API:
    # ... all other stuff here, skipped
    def run():
        app = flask.Flask('API')

        @app.route('/cmd1')
        def cmd1():
            self.cmd1()

        @app.route('/cmd2')
        def cmd2()
            self.cmd2()

        app.run()
```

I feel I done it wrong, because all docs says 'create flask app at module level'. But I don't want to do this - it messes up with my tests, and API is a small part of the larger application, which has own structure and conventions (each 'application' is a separate class running in one or more threads).

How can I use Flask inside class?

Comment: Do you run into a problem with this code? If so, what is it?

Comment: My variant with subfunctions is sucking with tests. I have no way to call 'cmd2' function from tests and this leaves part of the code without test coverage (and this brings stupid typo/traces). Lack of testing for this part of the code (subfunctions in inside 'run') was main reason for the question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Although this works it doesn't feel compliant with the Flask style guide. If you need to wrap a Flask application inside your project, create a separate class to your needs and add functions that should be executed

```
from flask import Flask, Response


class EndpointAction(object):

    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
        self.response = Response(status=200, headers={})

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.action()
        return self.response


class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    app = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)

    def run(self):
        self.app.run()

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, EndpointAction(handler))


def action():
    # Execute anything

a = FlaskAppWrapper('wrap')
a.add_endpoint(endpoint='/ad', endpoint_name='ad', handler=action)
a.run()
```

Some things to note here:

- `EndpointAction` is supposed to be a wrapper that will execute your function and generate an empty 200 response. If you want you can edit the functionality
- The endpoint handler can be anything that has a `__call__` method defined
- The endpoint name should be unique as it represents a view name
- Adding endpoints after the application is not possible as the thread will block once the application starts. You can enable it by running the application on a separate thread but changing the URL map on the fly is not advised, neither thread safe

Comment: Thank you. This is less elegant than decorators, but is in line with rest of the code in app.

Comment: when using decorator,I can refer to the specific methods like   `@app.route('/.../',methods=['POST']) `,so how should I do this in class _EndpointAction_?

Comment: Minor issue:

FlaskAppWrapper.app was specified at the CLASS level, not at the instance level inside \_\_init\_\_(). Every instance of the FlaskAppWrapper will share the same app object. If you were to create 2 FlaskAppWrappers with 2 different flask instances, both would share the 2nd one as the 2nd would override the 1st.

To mitigate this, remove `app = None` from above \_\_init\_\_. Any attribute defined in \_\_init\_\_ will be kept at the instance level.

Not a big deal here since you probably wouldn't have more than one FlaskAppWrapper, but good to keep in mind in general.

Answer (score 16):

So I just came across the library **[Flask-Classful](http://flask-classful.teracy.org/)**

which was really simple comparatively

To create a simple web app inside a class is this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView

app = Flask(__name__)

class TestView(FlaskView):

    def index(self):
    # http://localhost:5000/
        return "<h1>This is my indexpage</h1>"

TestView.register(app,route_base = '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Handling multiple route and dynamic route is also simple**

```py
class TestView(FlaskView):

    def index(self):
    # http://localhost:5000/
        return "<h1>This is my indexpage</h1>"

    def secondpage(self):
    # http://localhost:5000/secondpage
        return "<h1>This is my second</h1>"
    
    def thirdpage(self,name):
    # dynamic route
    # http://localhost:5000/thirdpage/sometext
        return "<h1>This is my third page <br> welcome"+name+"</h1>"

TestView.register(app,route_base = '/')
```

**Adding own route name with a different method that is also possible**

```py
from flask_classful import FlaskView,route

class TestView(FlaskView):

    def index(self):
    # http://localhost:5000/
        return "<h1>This is my indexpage</h1>"


    @route('/diffrentname')
    def bsicname(self):
    # customized route
    # http://localhost:5000/diffrentname
        return "<h1>This is my custom route</h1>"
TestView.register(app,route_base = '/')
```

This gives the potential to create separate class and handlers for a separate dependent and independent process and just import them as a package to run on the main file or wrapper file

```py
from package import Classname
Classname.register(app,route_base = '/')
```

which is really simple and object-oriented

Comment: That's an awasome lib! So many usefull options! Thx

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. It solved my problem though this solution has some disadvantages: You must have classes with constructor methods without arguments.

Comment: @Regis May: I'd recommend creating an isolated FlaskView class, instantiating it within your model class constructor, and passing in the reference of the model to the FlaskView after instantiation but before registering.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found! thanks a lot

Comment: How can I pass a DB instance to TestView?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar like a usual object-oriented way by inheriting class or creating object inside the constructor as constructor variable to access all over the class

Answer (score 10):

To complete Kostas Pelelis's answer, because I had some difficulty to find the why the Response wasn't directly using the Action returned value.

Here is another version of FLASK class without decorators :

```py
class EndpointAction(object):

    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action

    def __call__(self, *args):
        # Perform the action
        answer = self.action()
        # Create the answer (bundle it in a correctly formatted HTTP answer)
        self.response = flask.Response(answer, status=200, headers={})
        # Send it
        return self.response

class FlaskAppWrapper(object):

    def add_all_endpoints(self):
        # Add root endpoint
        self.add_endpoint(endpoint="/", endpoint_name="/", handler=self.action)

        # Add action endpoints
        self.add_endpoint(endpoint="/add_X", endpoint_name="/add_X", handler=self.add_X)
        # you can add more ... 

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, EndpointAction(handler)) 
        # You can also add options here : "... , methods=['POST'], ... "

    # ==================== ------ API Calls ------- ====================
    def action(self):
        # Dummy action
        return "action" # String that will be returned and display on the webpage
        # Test it with curl 127.0.0.1:5000

    def add_X(self):
        # Dummy action
        return "add_X"
        # Test it with curl 127.0.0.1:5000/add_X
```

Comment: Too much witchcraft man. I guess I'll rather stick to settting up all routing in a single page. :(

Comment: Well I don't see where the witchcraft is ... To me, decorators are much more witchcraft-like (as you don't know what happens, and it's kind of magic) that this. Here you see what, where and how is defined each element. 

If it's hard to read, go this way : add_all_endpoints => add_endpoint => EndpointAction(handler) => action
"add_url_rule" being a standard Flask call, the only "witchcraft" here. Give a try and you'll see. If you want to see more : https://github.com/Vincent-CIRCL/douglas-quaid/blob/master/carlhauser_server/API/API_server.py

Comment: Hmmm. What I wanted to do was have a module, say `app.py` and function to initialize the flask application. Then, I have `routes/` package where I have a `Route` class that I will extend with, say `AccountRoute`, and I'll have functions like `create`, `delete`, `find`. The usual CRUD stuff. So, in `app.py`, I'll initialize the app, and pass it to all descendant route classes. I haven't found an elegant approach without the witchcraft I'm referencing. I want it to be as verbose and as clear as possible without even needing a single line of comment. I'll check the link out. Thtanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of mixing class and routing that seems reasonable to me. See also https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyFlaskBootstrap4/issues/2 (where i am a committer)

This design has been criticized so in the project there are some improvements to this code.

```py
'''
Created on 27.07.2020

@author: wf
'''
from flask import Flask
from frontend.WikiCMS import Frontend
from flask import render_template
import os

class AppWrap:
    def __init__(self, host='0.0.0.0',port=8251,debug=False):
        self.debug=debug
        self.port=port
        self.host=host    
        scriptdir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.app = Flask(__name__,template_folder=scriptdir+'/../templates')
        self.frontend=None
        
    def wrap(self,route):
        if self.frontend is None:
            raise Exception("frontend is not initialized")
        content,error=self.frontend.getContent(route);
        return render_template('index.html',content=content,error=error)
        
    def run(self):
        self.app.run(debug=self.debug,port=self.port,host=self.host)   
        pass

    def initFrontend(self,wikiId):
        frontend=Frontend(wikiId)
        frontend.open()
    
appWrap=AppWrap()
app=appWrap.app    
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:route>')
def wrap(route):
    return appWrap.wrap(route)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appWrap.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

A sidenote/addition to @Kostas Pelelis Answer (Sorry can't comment yet):

For all of you who wonder how to integrate the methods of the endpoint route: have a look at the function description for app.add_url_rule.

As stated there you can use the "methods" parameter to change the default "GET" method.

Kostas Pelelis code changed to a "POST" type method would look like this:

(Example with methods integrated + Endpoint-class that returns whatever your action-function returns [a html for example]

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
class EndpointAction(object):

    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
        self.response = Response(status=200, headers={})

    def __call__(self, *args):
        response = self.action()
        if response != None:
            return response
        else
            return self.response


class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    app = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)

    def run(self):
    self.app.run()

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None, t_methods=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, EndpointAction(handler), methods=t_methods)


def action():
    # Execute anything
    print('i did something')

def returning_action():
    # Returning for example an index hello world page
    return render_template('index.html')

a = FlaskAppWrapper('wrap')
a.add_endpoint(endpoint='/ad', endpoint_name='ad', handler=action, req_methods=['POST'])

#just a little addition for handling of a returning actionhandler method 
#-> i added another endpoint but for a returning method

a.add_endpoint(endpoint='/', endpoint_name='index_page', handler=returning_action, req_methods=['GET']
a.run()
```

While the templates/index.html could look like this (note render_templates expects a templates-folder in the same location as your py-file with specified htmls in it):

> ```
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <title>Index Page</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

This index page addition is called when the index route 'ip-address-of-the-webapp/' is visited (via usual browser visit -> GET request).

*Edit: to show how it would look like if your action-methods had params (for example from a route param) here an updated version of the endpoint class and the action class

```
class EndpointAction(object):

    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
        self.response = Response(status=200, headers={})

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.action(**kwargs)
        if response != None:
            return response
        else
            return self.response

def param_action(param):
    # Execute something (print param)
    print(f'i did {param}')

[...]
a.add_endpoint(endpoint='/<param>', endpoint_name='parametric_action', handler=param_action, req_methods=['GET']
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

To run in a massive class object, or to avoid threading issues with flask, here its a slightly modified version of @kostas without disturbing the main class: (this way  `self.initialize_web_server` can run in Multiprocess environment combined with any number of indefinite loops concurrently).

flaskserver.py

```
from flask import Flask

class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    app = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)
        #self.endpoinAction = endpointAction 

    def run(self, args):
        self.app.run(**args)

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, handler)
```

The main class file:
Targetclass.py

```
import itertools
import time
from flaskserver import FlaskAppWrapper
from flask import Response, jsonify, redirect, request, url_for

class TargetClass(object):
    app = None

    def __init__(self, name, server_config, run_server=True):

        self.server_config = server_config
        if run_server:
            self.initialize_web_server()


    def initialize_web_server(self):
        self.app = FlaskAppWrapper(__name__, self.serve)
        self.app.add_endpoint(endpoint='/', endpoint_name='home', handler=self.home_page)
        self.app.add_endpoint(endpoint='/action', endpoint_name='metrics', handler=self.serve_metrics)

        self.app.run(self.server_config) # server_config tuple => (host, port, debug)


    def home_page(self):
        if request.headers.get('accept') == 'text/event-stream':
            def events():
                for i, c in enumerate(itertools.cycle('\|/-')):
                    yield "data: %s %d\n\n" % (c, i)
                    time.sleep(.1)  # an artificial delay
            return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
        return redirect(url_for('static', filename='index.html'))

    def serve_metrics(self):
        return jsonify(self.metrics)
    

server_config = { 'host' : 'localhost', 'port': 8626, 'debug': True }
TargetClass(name=__name__, server_config=server_config, run_server=True)
```

and a static html,
static/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>MyApp v1.0.1</title>
<style>
  #data {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/');
  source.onmessage = function(e) {
    $("#data").text(e.data);
  }
}
</script>
<div id="data">nothing received yet</div>
```