# How to add a new parameter to a Python API created using Flask

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing my Python API using `Flask`. This API accept only 1 parameter called `questionID`. I would like it to accept a second parameter called `lastDate`. I tried to look around on how to add this parameter, but couldn't find a good method to do this. My current code looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
import psycopg2
from pandas import read_sql
connenction_string = "DB Credentials'";

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class GetUserAnswers(Resource):
    def get(self, questionID):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(connenction_string);
        cursor = conn.cursor();

        userAnswers = read_sql('''
        select * from <tablename> where questionid = ''' + "'" + questionID + "' order by timesansweredincorrectly desc limit 15" +'''
        ''', con=conn)

        conn.commit();
        conn.close();

        result = {}
        for index, row in userAnswers.iterrows():
            result[index] = dict(row)
        return jsonify(result)

api.add_resource(GetUserAnswers, '/GetUserAnswers/<questionID>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

**Question 1:** I'm guessing I can accept the second parameter in the `get` definition. If this is not true, how should I accept the second parameter?

**Question 2:** How do I modify the `api.add_resource()` call to accept the second parameter?

**Question 3:** I currently use `http://localhost:5002/GetUserAnswers/<some question ID>` to call this API from the browser. How would this call change with a second parameter?

I have never developed an API before, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple parameters in in Flask approute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182696/multiple-parameters-in-in-flask-approute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider several adjustments to your code:

1. For simpler implementation as you have, use [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123448/how-do-decorated-functions-work-in-flask-python-app-route) in Flask API and avoid need to initialize and call the class object;
2. Use [parameterization](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) in SQL and avoid the potentially dangerous and messy string concatenation;
3. Avoid using the heavy data analytics library, `pandas`, and its inefficient row by row `iterrows` loop. Instead, handle everything with cursor object, specifically use [`DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=dictcursor) in `psycopg2`;

Refactored Python code (adjust assumption of how to use `lastDate`):

```
#... leave out the heavy pandas ...

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/GetUserAnswers', methods= ['GET'])
def GetUserAnswers():
    questionID = request.args.get('questionID', None)
    lastDate = request.args.get('lastDate', None)

    conn = psycopg2.connect(connenction_string)
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    userAnswers = '''SELECT * FROM <tablename> 
                     WHERE questionid = %s
                       AND lastdate = %s
                     ORDER BY timesansweredincorrectly DESC
                     LIMIT 15
                 '''
    # EXECUTE SQL WITH PARAMS
    cur.execute(userAnswers, (questionID, lastDate))

    # SAVE TO LIST OF DICTIONARIES
    result = [dict(row) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

Browser Call

```
http://localhost:5002/GetUserAnswers?questionID=8888&lastDate=2020-01-08
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using decorators, especially if you're using flask_restful specifically for this purpose. Adding resources and their routes in the main file and linking classes from external files is 10x more convenient in the long run than having routes in decorators spread around all over the place. Having to import app into external files might end up causing circular imports deadlock right away. You modified and assumed changes in the original question quite a lot just to avoid using path arguments, which is obviously what he is trying to do. (using flask_restful)

Comment: Interesting points, @c8999c3f964f64! Admittedly, I am not a keen Flask developer and as prefaced for simpler implementation I recommended the decorator approach but makes sense the use of classes for extended applications. But certainly I stand behind the latter approaches of SQL parameterization and non-Pandas use of which I am keen on!

Comment: absolutely, and I agree on those too. But the answer below has a more direct approach to solve the "another argument" to the argument in the path - question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add multiple parameters within the url path for example:

`http://localhost:5002/GetUserAnswers/<question_id>/answers/<answer_id>`

Then you need to add multiple parameters to your `get` method:

```py
def get(self, question_id, answer_id):
    # your code here
```

But if you instead want to add multiple query parameters to the url for example:
`http://localhost:5002/GetUserAnswers/<question_id>?lastDate=2020-01-01&totalCount=10>`

Then you can use request arguments:

```py
def get(self, question_id):
    lastDate = request.args.get('lastDate')
    totalCount = request.args.get('totalCount')
    # your code here
```