# Embedding flask inside a class with decorators

Tags: python, flask

I'am trying to use a flask inside a class, but i would like to use decorators

i've seen this subject 
[Using flask inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460846/using-flask-inside-class)

But so far so good no use of decorators inside, if no choice i will use this solution.

For the moment my code look like this :

```
class DM():
    def __init__(self, path=""):
        self.cors = CORS(self.app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
        self.host = "0.0.0.0"
        self.port = 9001

    class app(Flask):
        pass

    def PrintException(self):
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        lineno = tb.tb_lineno
        filename = f.f_code.co_filename
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
        return 'EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(
            filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj
        )

    @app.route("/product", methods=["POST", "GET", "OPTION"])
    def addProduct(self):
        try:
            data = request.data
            document = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
            return jsonify({"status":"ok","_id":str(document)})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"status": "ko", "exception": self.PrintException() + " " + str(e),"document":document})


    @app.after_request
    def after_request(self,response):
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
        return response
    def run(self):
        self.app.run(self.host, self.port)
```

but i have this error :

```
    @app.route("/product", methods=["POST", "GET", "OPTION"])
TypeError: route() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rule'
```

edit :

And i can't use self in decorators :

```
class DM():
    def __init__(self, path=""):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.cors = CORS(self, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
        self.host = "0.0.0.0"
        self.port = 9001


    def PrintException(self):
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        lineno = tb.tb_lineno
        filename = f.f_code.co_filename
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
        return 'EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(
            filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj
        )

    @app.route("/product", methods=["POST", "GET", "OPTION"])
    def addProduct(self):
        try:
            data = request.data
            document = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
            return jsonify({"status":"ok","_id":str(document)})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"status": "ko", "exception": self.PrintException() + " " + str(e),"document":document})

    @app.after_request
    def after_request(self,response):
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
        return response
    def run(self):
        self.app.run(self.host, self.port)
```

Regards

Comment: You should properly instantiate your app instead of subclassing Flask. Try this: `app = Flask("your_name")`.

Comment: The line throwing the exception does not exist in your code.

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov i can't use self if i choose this solution

Comment: @KlausD. corrected

Comment: What about assigning it in your __init__ method? Like `self.app` = Flask("your_name"). And then using @self.app decorator? I haven't tried anything like this before, but that should work

Comment: Btw, what is the reason for using flask inside a class? Do you create multiple flask applications in your project?

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov i want to use inheritance to tune a model micro service for each of client operation. I would like to have a good template then customise it for making a micro service for a specific client.

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov i've edited my question self.app don't work sadly in decorators

Comment: Do your microservices for different customers supposed to work simultaneously on the same server? If this is not the case, then you probably should consider making customizations in flask's configuration. If you really need to use classes, then maybe you can write your custom decorator function inside your class that will wrap original flask's route function.

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov it's also by curiosity to know how to do that

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve with your inheritance approach, but anyway, here is an idea that might help. Instead of using flask app inside a class, you may want to consider a [factory approach](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/). Code in your example may look as follows:

```
def create_application(app_name, config_filename, host, port):

    app = Flask(app_name)
    app.config_from_pyfile(config_filename)

    cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    @app.route("/product", methods=["POST", "GET", "OPTION"])
    def addProduct():
        try:
            data = request.data
            document = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
            return jsonify({"status":"ok","_id":str(document)})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"status": "ko", "exception": self.PrintException() + " " + str(e),"document":document})

    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                             "Content-Type,Authorization")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                             "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
        return response
```

This method will allow you to make necessary customizations passing different arguments to your factory function or different config files. And you still can you use decorators here